# Show that $|f(p_n)|<10^{-3}$ whenever $n>1$ but that $|p-p_n|<10^{-3}$ requires that $n>1000$.

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, roots

Let $f(x)=(x-1)^{10}$.

The root of the equation , $p=1$.

The approximates of the root, $p_n=1+\frac{1}{n}$

Show that $|f(p_n)|<10^{-3}$ whenever $n>1$ but that $|p-p_n|<10^{-3}$ requires that $n>1000$.

I started to solve it by the following way:

$|p-p_n|<10^{-3}\Rightarrow |1-(1+\frac{1}{n})|<10^{-3}\Rightarrow |\frac{1}{n}|<10^{-3}\Rightarrow |n|>1000\Rightarrow n>1000$

And

$f(p_n)=[(1+\frac{1}{n})-1]=\frac{1}{n}$; whenever $n>1$

But how to show

$|f(p_n)|<10^{-3}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the power of $10$ when you computed $f(p_n)$.

Comment: $f(p_n)=\frac{1}{n^{10}}$. But still i don't know how to show $|f(p_n)|<10^{-3}$ ?

Comment: well, do you know how to compare $n^{-10}$ and $(n+1)^{-10}$? can you see how small $2^{-10}$ is compared to $10^{-3}$?

Comment: $n>1000\Rightarrow n^{10}>(1000)^{10}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{n^{10}}<10^{-30}\Rightarrow f(p_n)<10^{-30}$. But what does it make sense? Can you please explain how to get $|f(p_n)|<10^{-3}$?

Comment: @tree you're considering $f(p_n)$ for $n>1$. note that $f$ is decreasing as a function of $p_n$, and already when $n=2$ we have $f(p_2) = 2^{-10}$, and this is much smaller than $10^{-3}$

Answer (score -1):

Show that $|f(pn)|<10^{-3}$ whenever $n>1$
$F(x)=(x-1)^{10}$ then $f(pn) =((1+1/n)-1)^{10} => |f(pn)| =(1/n)^{10}$
And $n>1$ then $|f(pn)| < = (1/2)^{10} = 1/1024$ and $1/1024 <10^{-3 }$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! To write math, please learn to use MathJax.